# bat %TIME% command formatting OR echoing time /t

Tags: batch-file, command

Is it possible to get the %TIME% command to echo the time **without** seconds and milliseconds? Alternatively, how can I echo the time /t command with other text in the same echo? eg. @echo %DATE% "time /t" %variable% >> text.txt

```
 I have tried - time /t 
               "time /t"
               %time /t%
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ECHO %time:~,-6%
```

or

```
ECHO %time:~0,-6%
```

which drops the last 6 characters of the `time` string.

You don't tell us what your `time` string is - this works for me, but I use 24-hr time. If you use am/pm, then you'd need to tell us exactly what your format is.

OR

try

```
set /?
```

from the prompt for documentation.